# Angular-cli requires root access

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I installed angular-cli using the command
npm install -g angular-cli.
However, everytime I try to run any ng command, it gives me an error saying

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/m041/.config/configstore/ember-cli.json'
You don't have access to this file.

at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
at Object.create.all.get (/home/m041/Bot/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
at Object.Configstore (/home/m041/Bot/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
at clientId (/home/m041/Bot/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/index.js:22:21)
at module.exports (/home/m041/Bot/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/index.js:65:19)
at module.exports (/home/m041/Bot/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/cli/index.js:106:10)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng:31:5
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:44:21
```

A temporary fix was to change the file permissions. However everytime I run an ng command, the permissions are reset!
My npm permissions are fixed. I can install packages without sudo. But I am facing an issue with cli. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: uninstall the angular cli client and try installing with,

`sudo npm install -g angular-cli`

I think it might be some permission issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this same issue using OSX 10.11.6 and solved it from here. I assume you are changing the file permissions on your program directory and not on the ember-cli.json file. This is a fix that has allowed me to get around the issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/696#issuecomment-233181380

```
sudo chown `$whoami` /Users/`$whoami`/.config/configstore/ember-cli.json
```

Given your traceback, it would seem you need to run the similar command:

```
sudo chown m041 /home/m041/.config/configstore/ember-cli.json
```