# Cannot install angular CLI as root user

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just tried to install angluar CLI as root user with the command `npm install -g --unasafe-perm @angular/cli` and I'm having the following issue :

```
root@ubuntu-:~/test# npm install -g --unasafe-perm @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /root/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
npm ERR! sh: 1: node: Permission denied

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-30T09_59_17_614Z-debug.log
```

Why is it impossible to install angular cli as root ?

I am using ubuntu 20.04 up to date !

Comment: This same problem was answer in here, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511987/angular-cli-requires-root-access) is the post

Comment: Not really since I'm already logged in as root ...

Comment: Did you try `sudo`?  I was having an issue too, just tied sudo and it was able to install